# Structure of a CQRS event store

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

I'm currently trying to understand how to build the internal structure of an event store. What I got so far:

- An event store has two tables (collections, ...), one for aggregates and one for events.
- The aggregates table contains the following data: `aggregateId` (which will probably be a GUID) and the `aggregateVersion` (which is an integer that simply represents the number of the last event that influenced this aggregate).
- The events table contains the following data: `eventId` (again, a GUID), `aggregateId` (which the event belongs to), `payload`, and a `version` (which is simply an integer that describes the order of the events).

Is this correct so far?
Should events be ordered by using an integer? Or should they be ordered based on a timestamp? What are the advantages of each? What are the disadvantages?

Comment: I'm also considering the integer (auto incremented by database) versus a timestamp question. An auto incremented database id is obviously guaranteed to be absolutely unique, but it might make recovering from some failover scenarios impossible or at best difficult.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would suggest you to have a look at [Jonathan Oliver's EventStore](https://github.com/joliver/EventStore) for reference.

In the SQL persistence version there's only one table. You could easily live without the aggregate table and store the aggregateId in the events table. The latest version could be retrieved by using a max() query.

Other than that I think you should consider having headers in the events table, cause there are always interesting metadata that you don't want to store in the events themselves.

And also, I think you should add a date column in the events table.

Finally, you probably want to have some sort of flag that states if the event has been dispatched downstream or not. This addition enable you to write in one thread or process and dispatch in another.

Aaand there, I have sort of suggested the structure of Jonathans EventStore.

Comment: Booleans and indexes are not friends.

Comment: Yves, are you referring to the dispatched flag? I think it needs to be there regardless. I'm luckily not an expert on SQL indexes, but how would a 'datetime null' do in terms of indexing?

Comment: If your index refers to either 99% of the set, or each value in the index referring to a unique row, what is an index worth (either it does not serve the query well or it becomes an insert/update nightmare, finding a balance is difficult)? I would go for a write-ahead-of-time separate table.

Comment: Bottom line, for me, is that a bus concern does not belong in an eventstore (although - like anything - it's not something I'm religious about).

Comment: Ditch the dispatched flag. Projections / views can be responsible for tracking their progress. This'll also allow you to write to an append only store as well as simplifying backup and replication.

Answer (score 4):

Look at http://geteventstore.com/ - this version by Greg Young is also has [source available for your perusal [with a BSD 3-clause license on GitHub]](https://github.com/eventstore).

Answer (score 4):

I can't add much to Mikael's answer.

Here's just one more thing as a reference: A few years ago Greg Young wrote down his thoughts about an event store implementation. The document can be found at http://cqrs.wordpress.com/documents/building-event-storage/

Although I believe his approach has evolved in the meantime as well.

Answer (score 2):

Aggregates have to do with cqrs but not directly with an event-store.
You're right there are two collections but these are events and snapshots.
For more details look at:
https://github.com/jamuhl/nodeEventStore

Comment: Well, this is in contrast to what Mark Nijhof (and assumed Greg Young) say (according to http://cre8ivethought.com/blog/2010/02/05/cqrs-event-sourcing): "you basically need to have one collection that describes all the different objects that the event store has persisted this includes the Id and the Version. Then another collection will contain all the serialized events for each different object and they should be retrievable by the object Id ordered by their Version. So to simplify this, in a RDBMS this would mean 2 tables, in total."

Comment: anyway no need for two collections (if not doing snapshots). have a look at https://github.com/joliver/EventStore for another implementation.

Comment: and why you need to build your own? there are already two eventstore implementations in node.js: 
https://github.com/jamuhl/nodeEventStore 
or 
https://github.com/brighthas/cqrsnode.store

why not contributing to them?